# UEFI v/s Lagecy boot

Tags: windows-8, livecd, uefi, backtrack

I don't have much idea on uefi and legacy boot modes. Actually I have Windows8 installed in UEFI boot mode, And I just want to use the backtrack in live mode without installing it using legacy mode.

So just want to confirm it would not cause any problem to windows 8 once i have done my work on backtrack. Actually I previously got windows 8 lost due to installation of Ubuntu 12.04 in legacy mode.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to boot from LiveCD, do it in Legacy Mode, and it will not do you any damage (unless you do it yourself, or have a malware LiveCD).
You will need to switch back to UEFI to boot Windows. 
There can be UEFI LiveCDs too. 
Your problems with Ubuntu were because you were inattentive during installation, UEFI has nothing to do with it.